# Access will not accept a many to one relationship

Tags: database

I want to create a many-to-one relationship between my customer and booking tables, however when I enforce referential integrity, only one-to-one shows.

I have several other tables that have worked correctly, so this seems to be a bug; can anyone offer any suggestions?

Summary:

- Customer ID is the unique primary key in the Customer table
- Customer ID is a foreign key in the booking table
- Access is enforcing a one-one relationship between the two

How can I create this many-to-one relationship?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: What database is this? Are you using an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)? If so, what language is it, and what framework is it?

Comment: dBase, far from any ORM, it's from the late '80s, sort of Interbase alike.

Comment: Does Booking Table have a primary key of BookingID?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've figured out the answer and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who responded, it turned out I had accidentally set the field indexing property to NO Duplicates.